# Forbidden access for google signin

Tags: android, google-signin

In my application(which is live on playstore) have used google login.
Suddenly this morning when I started testing the live app, I got login issue for google. I started checking the reason for it, i found out I am getting following response from this API : https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token/

response : {
     "error": "internal_failure",
     "error_description": "Forbidden"
    }

getting http code as 403.

Since its the live app, havn't made any changes in code, then why am I facing the issue?

Comment: If someone is giving a -ve vote, then please also add a comment to know why

Comment: can you please post your logcat output ?

Comment: maybe related: https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript/issues/43

Answer (score 0):

Try the auth uri `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` (which can be found in a newly generated .json for the private key of a service account).

Looks like `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token/` is obsolete.